# Apparent steriliser residue left on bottles; is this safe?

Tags: sanitation

A few months ago I bottled using Wilko's Bruclens steriliser:
http://www.wilko.com/homebrew-accessories+equipment/wilko-cleaner-and-steriliser-100g/invt/0022658

After sterilising I gave the bottles a few rinses with cold water. After bottling I noticed this white film on a number of the bottles:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oi27E.jpg

My questions are:
1. Does this mean there is some steriliser left behind in the bottles?
2. What are the consequences if you consume some left-behind steriliser of this type with your beer?

Edit: I can't rule out that the film was caused by an oxi clean product from when I was cleaning the bottles, so it would be nice to know of any risks with that as well.

Thanks!

Comment: can you post the ingredients that are listed on the package, i couldn't find a reliable source on whats in that cleaner.....but others have complained about  the same white residue.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any containers lying around, but I did find this: https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/a/12977/15553

Answer (score 3):

Looks like oxidized matter. Definitely not "clean". Rewash them.

Wash bottles with hot water and normal dish soap to get clean. Then a 3 min soak in No rinse sanitizer like StarSan, then dry inverted just before bottling.

Comment: +1 for the hot water.  It looks like Bruclens is sodium percarbonate like PBW or OxyClean, which all rinse off much cleaner if you rinse with warmer water than what you used for cleaning.

Comment: I would say to rinse, it has chlorine in the ingredients. I would not want to drink any beer that has come into contact with that white powder.....but that is my opinion.  If it was just oxy, i would have a different opinion.

Answer (score 1):

If I can't put a teaspoon of it in my mouth, then I don't want it in my beer. I always rinse after using no rinse sanitizer but we have good water here. If you see anything in the bottle, then clean it again or kill it with bleach. Then sanitize and proceed bottling. Brewdog333

Answer (score 0):

Oxiclean can leave a white powdery looking film - especially if the water is cold.  I seem to recall hard tap water might contribute as well.  If you scrub with water and a bottle brush you might see lines where the bristles rub it off.

A quick wash in an acid like StarSan will take it off pretty easily.